# CSP nonce isn't working in older versions of Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy, nonce

I have the following CSP header:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://*.example.com; script-src 'nonce-OWEwM2Q2YWMtYjc5NS00NmQxLWI3MGItNWRiNGJkOGNlNzZm' 'self' data: https://*.google-analytics.com https://*.facebook.net 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://*.fonts.net 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data: https://media.example.com https://*.google-analytics.com https://*.doubleclick.net https://*.facebook.com http: https:; media-src 'self' data: https://media.example.com
```

And the following script element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="OWEwM2Q2YWMtYjc5NS00NmQxLWI3MGItNWRiNGJkOGNlNzZm">var data="some data";</script>
```

It works fine in modern browsers, but in version of Chrome <= 40 I see the following error:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-OWEwM2Q2YWMtYjc5NS00NmQxLWI3MGItNWRiNGJkOGNlNzZm' 'self' data: https://*.google-analytics.com https://*.facebook.net 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I've done some Googling and haven't found any other relevant references to this error. Anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: Do you have "Enable experimental Web Platform features" turned on in about:flags?

Comment: No, as I assume most of my users won't have it on either. Is it unsupported otherwise? It's pretty misleading of that error message to suggest there's something wrong with my nonce.

Comment: The nonce attribute is a CSP2 feature and CSP2 wasn’t officially supported in any release version of Chrome before Chrome 40. Before that it was only experimentally supported and required that flag to be set. There were actually some syntax changes to the spec in there somewhere before that as well—there was an earlier version of the syntax that Chrome implemented and then needed to change when the spec changed. So dunno but you may be running into that. Chrome 40 shipped more than 2 years ago, so it’s hard to recall what the state of things was with CSP2 features in the releases prior to that